# How to download a file from server using ftp and how to save that file in my local folder

Tags: php

this is my code but this is not working whats a problem in this code.u have any another code.give me idea to download a file from server using ftp.i am trying this code in my localhost also in my own server.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("ftpfile/file.csv", 'w');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp:http://www.address.com/file.csv"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing one of two things: the fopen call failed (and you're not checking if it succeeded by seeing if `$file !== false`), or the double-use of _returntransfer AND _file is not acting as you expect.

returntransfer tells curl to return the retrieved data in the exec call, instead of outputting it directly to the browser. I suspect that if you did `$data = curl_exec($curl); file_put_contents('ftpfile/file.csv', $data)` you'd end up with a properly populatd file. So... either remove the returntransfer option, or eliminate the whole _file business and output the file yourself using what the _exec call returns.

Comment: this is correct or not......$curl = curl_init();
$data = curl_exec($curl); 
$file = file_put_contents('ftpfile/file.csv', $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp:http://www.address.com/file.csv"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_exec($curl);

Comment: above the code correct or not...because this is not working .it is showing <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\new\ajaxpages\datasget-ajax.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />